# Company wiki to share info with coworkers

Tags: self-hosted, wiki

Which private wiki to you recommend to share sensitive information in a company? Features need:

- Searching for information
- Linking related information, jump around from wiki page to wiki page
- Categories / tags easily organize your content

Confidence is crucial, need to run it on private server. But I like [Slite](https://slite.com/) as well.

Comment: How is it relevant that you like Slite? Does it mean you also consider using a hosted solution? Or should the wiki (for self-hosting) be like Slite?

Comment: I don’t know Slitr deeply, or use it, but I want get suggestions at least with this service level, user experience.

Answer (score 2):

There are a large number of wikis to choose from. I've personally tried DokuWiki, MediaWiki and MoinMoin and had no trouble at all implementing them and I'm not at all skilled with web technologies. I particularly liked DokuWiki. The best way to compare and contrast wikis is https://www.wikimatrix.org. The three requirements you cite are nearly always available either natively or with a plugin. A bigger differentiator is whether the wiki supports WYSIWYG editing or uses a simple markup language. Depending on what you are documenting, look also for how tables, media and equations are handled.

Comment: I’ve used abd adminnef  wikis - from the original C3 wiki, twiki, zeiki, MoinMoin, Mediawiki, Conflurnce, etc. One consideration: how much time do you want to spent as wiki admin? How will you back it up? I have developed a dislike of database storage for wikis because many databases cannot be backed up by standard filesystem backups. Personallu, I like my wikis to be based on text files.

Comment: @KrazyGlew Another plus for DokuWiki which is file based.

Comment: My gosh, my comment was badly entered!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider https://archbee.io

I've built it to give developer teams the best knowledge sharing experience. 
Build your team's knowledge base and product docs for your customers.

We are not able to give you the software to self host it yet, but we have it in the plan, we're cleaning up the code to open source it first :)